# In the C source code of Ruby, where is the Ruby operator `=` defined?

Tags: c, ruby

I'd like to read the logic code of `=`, but can't find it.

**UPDATE:**

I found the `test_multi` method text/ruby/test_assignment.rb. It's Ruby code, but seems will let me to the destination.

The reason I want to check the code is find how it handles multi-assignment. Like `a,b,c = [1,2,3]`.

**UPDATE:**

I found keywords "MASGN" and led me to

`compile_massign(rb_iseq_t *iseq, LINK_ANCHOR *ret, NODE *node, int poped)` in compile.c

http://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/e39eb9dab50eaa681467e51145b37cdc11667830#diff-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "the C source code of Ruby". Ruby is a programming language. Programming languages don't have source code (only compilers and interpreters do), they have *specifications*.

The specification of multiple assignment is in section *11.3.1.3 Multiple Assignments* on pages 59–62 of the current (2009-12-01) [ISO Ruby Draft Specification](http://Ruby-Std.NetLab.Jp/) and in [`language/variables_spec.rb`](https://GitHub.Com/RubySpec/RubySpec/blob/master/language/variables_spec.rb) (search for "*multiple*", unfortunately the tests are a bit scattered around the file) in the executable [RubySpec](http://RubySpec.Org/).

A nice overview of a possible implementation can be found in the Rubinius compiler (sorry, no C source code here, either) in lines 482–607 of [`lib/compiler/ast/variables.rb`](https://GitHub.Com/EvanPhx/Rubinius/blob/master/lib/compiler/ast/variables.rb#L482-607).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll find any code for `=`.

The `=` will be part of the grammar rules which define the Ruby language and the parser(written in C) will make use of the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/ruby_1_9_2/parse.y
line 1088-1116

```
| var_lhs tOP_ASGN command_call
        {
        /*%%%*/
        value_expr($3);
        if ($1) {
            ID vid = $1->nd_vid;
            if ($2 == tOROP) {
            $1->nd_value = $3;
            $$ = NEW_OP_ASGN_OR(gettable(vid), $1);
            if (is_asgn_or_id(vid)) {
                $$->nd_aid = vid;
            }
            }
            else if ($2 == tANDOP) {
            $1->nd_value = $3;
            $$ = NEW_OP_ASGN_AND(gettable(vid), $1);
            }
            else {
            $$ = $1;
            $$->nd_value = NEW_CALL(gettable(vid), $2, NEW_LIST($3));
            }
        }
        else {
            $$ = NEW_BEGIN(0);
        }
        /*%
        $$ = dispatch3(opassign, $1, $2, $3);
        %*/
        }
```